# My task is to create a countCharacters() method that returns words length, but I have to do it Recursively

Tags: java

This is my format so far:

```
public class CompSci12A2Recursion {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void countCharacters(String s){
        String CharCount;
        Integer intCharCount;
        CharCount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(s);
        if (CharCount.length() == 1){
            System.out.println(CharCount);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        CompSci12A2Recursion mySimpleObject = new CompSci12A2Recursion();
        CompSci12A2Recursion.countCharacters("Type in a word, and it will count how many characters are in it.");

    }

}
```

I'm trying to make it so that whatever is Typed in the MessageBox, it will let the user know how much characters are in said word.

Comment: 1) Variable names should start with lowercase letter, i.e. `charCount`. --- 2) `charCount` is a bad name, since it's not a count of characters. --- 3) `intCharCount` should be type `int`, not `Integer`. --- 4) Why do you create instance of `CompSci12A2Recursion` when your method is `static`? --- 5) To get number of characters in a string, call `length()`. Oh, you already do that. So what is your question again?

Comment: `CharCount.length()` has the length of the String already.

Comment: @D M has to be recursive

Comment: If someone is telling you you're not allowed to use `.length()` and must recursively count characters in a string then you're either asking for people to do your homework or working for someone who shouldn't be in charge.

Answer (score 1):

Recursively eh? Try this:

```
public int count (String str){ 
     if (str.length == 1)
          return 1;
     else if (str.length == 0)
          return 0;
     else 
          return count(str.substring(1)) + 1; 
}
```

Comment: If someone could format this appropriately I'd appreciate it, my phone doesn't support the formatting

Comment: Oh, alright, didn't think the one-line writing was a good style

Comment: Uh, isn't this going to be an infinite loop?  str never changes.

Comment: Better, but there's a nitpick: you'll get an error if the length is 0.

Comment: I keep rushing through it... changing again

Comment: @Rocket6488 Code better on your phone! ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. If `s.equals("")` return 0. You may also use `isEmpty()` method of String to test this.
2. Otherwise return 1 + recursive call. For recursive call, s should be shortened by 1 character. This may be done via substring method of String.

Answer (score 0):

For a good performance, you probably want to use `StringBuilder` in your recursive function.

If the given string's length in UTF-16 chars is good enough, a simple recursion will do:

```
public static int charCount (StringBuilder string){ 
    if (string.length() == 0)
        return 0;
    else {
        string.deleteCharAt(0);
        return charCount(string) + 1;
    }
}
```

However, if you want to get the number of Unicode characters, you will probably do something like this:

```
public static int unicodeCount (StringBuilder string) {
    if (string.length() == 0)
        return 0;
    else {
        int firstCharacter = Character.codePointAt(string, 0);
        int characterLength = Character.charCount(firstCharacter);
        string.delete(0, characterLength);
        return unicodeCount(string) + 1;
    }
}
```

This allows you to count characters above U+10000 inclusive (the `MUSICAL SYMBOL G CLEF` U+1D11E  for instance) as one character; the `charCount` version will count these characters as two, because they are coded as surrogate pairs.

You can use it in your `countCharacters` function with:

```
String string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(s);
System.out.println(charCount(new StringBuilder (string)));
System.out.println(unicodeCount(new StringBuilder (string)));
```

Comment: He's asking for a recursive method, NOT one that already exists

Comment: @Rocket6488 Thank you for information. I am going to edit my answer now.